# The application cannot access files that were pushed via adb

Tags: python, android, mobile, adb, file-permissions

I'm trying to swap app files using adb on Android 13, but the app throws errors saying it can't access the files.

I've tried granting permissions with *chmod* and *chown* to match the app's user, but it's not enough.

Here's the weird part: dragging and dropping files with scrcpy works flawlessly. **I can cut from Downloads and paste to the desired location via mixploer, and the app reads them without issue.** This makes me think it's an adb-specific permission problem. **I have root**

Anyone else seen this? How can I fix permissions for adb and push those files successfully?

Comment: Please include the ful path of the files you mention and the commands you used for changing permissions.